# How to get specific changes from ChangeListener in Realm

Tags: android, listener, onchange, realm

Im trying to use the Realm-Database for my Android App.
When I want to use the `RealmChangeListener` in my realm, it auto-creates the Method "`onChange`". That means if something is changed in the database, the program  executes this method.

I want to get detailed information about *what* has been changed. That would be so cool!

Does anyone know something about this feature? I'll post the Code below for better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

Greetings,
John

Code:

```
Realm realm =  Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext()); 
realmListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange() {
    Log.i("realmtest","some values in the database have been changed");
}};
realm.addChangeListener(realmListener);
```

Comment: We post an event to the main looper when we persist, and we are subscribed to that event (Otto event bus).

Comment: You can use RxJava http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534131/realm-io-java-notifications-how-to-listen-for-changes-only-in-certain-table/34698497#34698497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine grained notifications are now supported.

[Source 1](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/4191)

[Sample recyclerview](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/pull/83/files#diff-5db60168121b71f755fdff3c780e4c3dR56)

Answer (score 2):

Fine grained notifications are not supported yet, but we're working on it :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks. this helped me a lot :)
Im looking forward to use this feature! It would help so much.

Comment: @Jaiprakash Soni I think that answer the question pretty well: there is no current support.

Comment: Using addListener in react-native realm on iOS results in too many renders.  I think I will go back to putting all realm transactions in the react reducer and let actions change state.